# Which StackExchange site should I have posted this to?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I just posted

- [How can I get my Mountain Lion Mac to have Apache serve up content on port 80?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59396/how-can-i-get-my-mountain-lion-mac-to-have-apache-serve-up-content-on-port-80)

to [Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com), and it rejected most of the tags I proposed (notably apache2 and httpd), which is a not-so-subtle clue that I was posting in the wrong site.

Which site should I have posted it to? [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Maybe [su]? Apple.SE is more about hardware than software.

Answer (score 1):

The question's on topic for either [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com). You might want to clarify what happens when you state:

> Since I have gotten it back, Apache appears to start without reported error, but I can't connect, even from the same machine

Does the browser mention any error messages or the like.

---

Having said that, there are few OS X questions on [Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com), and looking at the past questions and given that your question is slanted towards Apache + OS X, there's no reason to believe why it would be offtopic for [Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

*Note:  I'm not a [Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com) regular, so feel free to correct me if I'm wrong*

Comment: "Does the browser mention any error messages or the like?" It gives the standard "can't connect" error. And if I try to telnet to localhost on port 80, it says that the connection is refused. I believe, because a lack of httpd processes shown by ps aux, that it is either not starting or starting but dying. I've tried a couple of channels, and none of them give evidence that httpd processes are running or that anything is listening on 80.

Comment: @JonathanHayward you should add that to the question :-)